# FCPX Continues to Crash on one project

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have a project that seems to keep crashing FCPX. The library for it is pretty massive (all in all about 175gb), but its running off a brand new Thunderbolt external with 2.5TB of space free. Problem report screen shot is below. Is it the App or is the library corrupted? How do I fix this, I need to turn this project out soon.

Also, my machine is brand new:
4GHz Intel Core i7
32GB RAM
AMD Radeon R9 M395X 4096MB
EL Capitan 10.11.6

The project itself is somewhat complex, lots of color correction and chroma keying. Not sure if that has any effect on it.

Please help?

Matt

[image]

Comment: You are much better off taking a crash report to Apple and/or the Apple discussions community.  I think that such a specific problem report is beyond the scope of this Video Production forum.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is on your Mac, create a new user profile from the System Prefs Panel, then log in using that user and try to open up the project using the new users profile.

If this woks then I would finish off the project ASAP and once finished, do a system restore on the Mac to get rid of any errors or issues that might happen again